# Automapper failed to create map with two different entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, .net-7.0

Below are two entities

```
public class User
    {
        public int UId { get; set; }

        public string UName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string UUsername { get; set; } = null!;

        public string UPassword { get; set; } = null!;

        public string? UEmail { get; set; }

        public int ULevel { get; set; }

        public int? UAddBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UAddDate { get; set; }

        public int? ULastEditBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ULastEditDate { get; set; }

        public string? UActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class UsersProvider
    {
        public int UpId { get; set; }

        public int UpUserId { get; set; }

        public int? UpProvId { get; set; }

        public int? UpAddBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpAddDate { get; set; }
    }

And below DTO for which has combined entities response 

 public class GetLoginResponse
    {
        public string? Active { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? RecruitmentCenterID { get; set; }
    }
```

below is mapper class

```
public class GetLoginResponseMapper: Profile
    {
        public GetLoginResponseMapper()
        {
            //CreateMap<User, GetLoginResponse>(MemberList.Source);
            //CreateMap<UsersProvider, GetLoginResponse>(MemberList.Source)
            //      .ForMember(d => d.RecruitmentCenterID, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.UpProvId));

            //CreateMap<GetLoginResponse, (User, UsersProvider)>(MemberList.Destination)
            //       .ForMember(x => x.Item1, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x))
            //       .ForMember(x => x.Item2, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.RecruitmentCenterID))
            //       .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<(User user, UsersProvider usersProvider), GetLoginResponse>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UActive))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Password, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UPassword))
                    .ForMember(d => d.UserID, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UId))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Level, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.ULevel))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UName))
                    .ForMember(d => d.RecruitmentCenterID, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.usersProvider.UpProvId));

            //CreateMap<User, GetLoginResponse>();
        }
    }
```

below is handler which is mapping output to GetLoginResponse

```
 public class GetLoginQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetLoginRequest, List<GetLoginResponse>>
    {
        private readonly ICrewApplicationDBContext _iCrewApplicationDBContext;

        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetLoginQueryHandler(ICrewApplicationDBContext iCrewApplicationDBContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _iCrewApplicationDBContext = iCrewApplicationDBContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Task<List<GetLoginResponse>> Handle(GetLoginRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //return _iCrewApplicationDBContext.user.ProjectTo<GetLoginResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).Where(a => a.UUsername == request.UserName).ToListAsync();

            return (from u in _iCrewApplicationDBContext.user
                    join up in _iCrewApplicationDBContext.usersProvider on u.UId equals up.UpUserId
                    into loginResult
                    from lr in loginResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where u.UName == request.UserName
                    select new GetLoginResponse
                    {
                        Active = u.UActive,
                        Password = u.UPassword,
                        UserID = u.UId,
                        Level = u.ULevel,
                        Name = u.UName,
                        RecruitmentCenterID = lr.UpProvId 
                    })   
                    .ProjectTo<GetLoginResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

But when try to access this method from webAPI controller got below exception

System.InvalidOperationException: Missing map from CrewApplication.Architecture.Application.AdminLogin.GetLoginResponse to CrewApplication.Architecture.Application.AdminLogin.GetLoginResponse. Create using CreateMap<GetLoginResponse, GetLoginResponse>.
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.ProjectionBuilder.CreateProjection(ProjectionRequest& request, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.ProjectionBuilder.CreateProjection(ProjectionRequest request)
at AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1() at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor) at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey& key)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.ProjectionBuilder.GetProjection(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Object parameters, MemberPath[] membersToExpand)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ToCore(IQueryable source, Type destinationType, IConfigurationProvider configuration, Object parameters, IEnumerable`1 memberPathsToExpand) at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ToCore[TResult](IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, Object parameters, IEnumerable`1 memberPathsToExpand)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ProjectTo[TDestination](IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, Object parameters, Expression`1[] membersToExpand) at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ProjectTo[TDestination](IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, Expression`1[] membersToExpand)
at CrewApplication.Architecture.Application.AdminLogin.GetLoginQueryHandler.Handle(GetLoginRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\VivekChavan\source\repos\CrewApplication.Architecture.Api\CrewApplication.Architecture.Application\AdminLogin\GetLoginQueryHandler.cs:line 32
at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Handle>g__Handler|0() at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1 request, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at CrewApplication.Architecture.Api.Controllers.LoginController.GetAdminLoginResponseByUserNameAsync(String userName) in C:\Users\VivekChavan\source\repos\CrewApplication.Architecture.Api\CrewApplication.Architecture.Api\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 23
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I have try with different ways to map this object which i have commented out.

```
 public GetLoginResponseMapper()
        {
            //CreateMap<User, GetLoginResponse>(MemberList.Source);
            //CreateMap<UsersProvider, GetLoginResponse>(MemberList.Source)
            //      .ForMember(d => d.RecruitmentCenterID, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.UpProvId));

            //CreateMap<GetLoginResponse, (User, UsersProvider)>(MemberList.Destination)
            //       .ForMember(x => x.Item1, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x))
            //       .ForMember(x => x.Item2, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.RecruitmentCenterID))
            //       .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<(User user, UsersProvider usersProvider), GetLoginResponse>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UActive))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Password, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UPassword))
                    .ForMember(d => d.UserID, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UId))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Level, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.ULevel))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.user.UName))
                    .ForMember(d => d.RecruitmentCenterID, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.usersProvider.UpProvId));

            //CreateMap<User, GetLoginResponse>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split your linq expression into serval parts like:

```
var loginresponse = from u in _context.User
                    join up in _context.UsersProvider on u.UId equals up.UpUserId
                    into loginResult
                    from lr in loginResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where u.UName == "CusName"
                    select new GetLoginResponse() ;

var targetlist = loginresponse.ProjectTo<GetLoginResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
```

You would found you are mapping  GetLoginResponse to GetLoginResponse just as the error indicates

[image]

remove `.ProjectTo<GetLoginResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)` to avoid mapping twice